# Good tools for spatial specification of a moving shot?

Tags: animation, shooting, multi-camera

I'm still not very familiar with the tools available out there, so I'm hoping the community can provide some pointers:

At 10:03 in this video, they show a simple animation of how camera and talent will move for a shot.

I believe an animation like this can be done with After Effects, but are there tools specifically spatially depicting shots?  I.e. visualize the position and movement of camera & talent in the context of the set. It can be static images rather than an animation, since sometimes all the players aren't moving, but ideally the user can choose between the two.